# Continuity of $f(x)=x^2$ between the usual and the complement finite topology

Tags: general-topology

> Study if 
>   $$f:(\mathbb{R},\tau_u)\to (\mathbb{R},\tau_{\text{CF}})$$
>   $$x\mapsto f(x)=x^2$$
>   is continuous.

$\tau_u$ is the usual topology and $\tau_{\text{CF}}$ is the complement finite topology. I have lots of problems with these questions because I don't know how to begin and write formally the answer. I appriciate if someone can give me some help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function $f$ is continuous if $f^{-1}(F)$ is closed for every closed set $F$. Closed sets in $\tau_{\text{CF}}$ are exactly the finite sets (and $\Bbb R$).

For each $x\in Im (f)$, the set $f^{-1}(\{x\})$ has no more than two elements.

Then take any set $F$ closed under the $\tau_{\text{CF}}$ topology. If $F=\Bbb R$ then $f^{-1}(F)=[0,\infty)$ which is closed. Otherwise, $F$ is finite. Then, $f^{-1}(F)$ is also finite. Actually, $\#f^{-1}(F)\le2\#F$. Since finite sets are closed also under the usual topology, $f$ is continuous.

Comment: I know that definition. The problem is how to follow

Comment: Why no more than two elements?

Comment: How many numbers can have the same square?

Comment: I got it. You were very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

By topological definition of continuity you take a closed $C$ set from $(\mathbb{R},\tau_{CF})$ and see the pre-image by $f$, so as $C$ is a finite set, $F:=f^{-1}(C)$ is also finite and then $F$ is closed set of $(\mathbb{R},\tau_U)$ with shows $f$ is continuous.